# How can I back-track errors that are thrown by external libraries in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Sometimes I get an error thrown by a core library in the browser console after I've made a change in my Angular code. Sometimes an error is thrown by a core library and I'm not sure what I did to invoke it. In the second case it is very difficult for me to find what part of my code causes the error to be thrown. Example, a console error such as this:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
    at BaseFxDirectiveAdapter.BaseFxDirective._getDisplayStyle (base.js:63)
    at BaseFxDirectiveAdapter.BaseFxDirective (base.js:17)
    at new BaseFxDirectiveAdapter (base-adapter.js:23)
    at new ClassDirective (class.js:33)
```

There's this and other variations (depending on the core module or external module that throws it).

I have tried stepping through my code in the Dev tools, but I end up traversing through external file after external file. This is a nightmare.

Any ideas how I can back-track these thrown errors to my code?

Comment: You may find this article on async debugging in chrome userful. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. That article is very useful, but doesn't solve my current problem.